# OpenCV - Method 'knnMatch' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, opencv, include

I have just a little problem with the right resource.
I am using opencv 2.4.8 and I couldn't find the right resource for **knnMatch()**. I tried the following which didn't work:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>
//#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
//#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>
```

Can someone say me the right resource? Also google didn't help me.

tried to find the 3 nearest matches for two descriptors with keypoints:

```
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher; 
matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsLeft, descriptorsRight,3);
```

Comment: Can you show where does the error occur?

Comment: @Elried: I tried to find the 3 nearest matches for two descriptors with keypoints:     Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher;
       matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsLeft, descriptorsRight,3);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `Ptr<DescriptorMatcher>` so you should dereference it in order to call the method...

```
matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsLeft, descriptorsRight,3); //error
matcher->knnMatch(descriptorsLeft, descriptorsRight,3); // should be better
```